# How to modify request to include new url parameter

Tags: node.js, parameters, request

I want to add a new url parameter to the req.params before sending the response back . I tried the below way . But it's not working

```
router.get('/customers', function(req, res) {
    req.params.customerId = someval ;
   // proceed my implementation
});
```

Is there any specific way to do this or is this impossible to do ?

Comment: The question is why you want to add to `req`? How you want to use this new parameter?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a parameter in the request send to the server, you just have to :

```
router.get('/customers/:customerId', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.customerId);
});
```

If you want to add a parameter in the request to send back, so I don't know why you want to do that, but you can perhaps do this with setting the new parameters in `req` and call a [`res.redirect`](http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#res.redirect) on the good route, or play with the [`res.location`](http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#res.location) function.